# How can I generate a spreadsheet of a folder structure on my computer with folder sizes included?

Tags: terminal, filesystem, zsh, csv

I'd like to make a spreadsheet of a folder structure in my filesystem. Given a parent folder or volume as the input, the output should include:

1. Subfolders to the nth level (user-specified)
2. A clean/readable visual format showing the folder names and their hierarchy (perhaps each next level in the path breaks out to a new column)
3. The total size of each folder in GB

You can't copy and paste more than the names of files directly from Finder, so I understand Terminal / zsh would be the way to achieve this. What command line code would output this result?

**What I've tried:**

Changing directory to the desired folder in Terminal and running `du -k -d 3` gets me somewhat close (`-k` meaning kilobytes and `-d 3` meaning depth of 3). But it's quite an unruly list that is tedious to translate into a spreadsheet format.

I'd still prefer to export a .csv from that, generate GB to the second decimal place instead of KB, and perhaps have each level in the path name break out into a new column of the .csv.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `man du` and `man find` might be good places to start.

Comment: Did you try to just run `du`,  and play with the options available?

Comment: More specifically, `du -k .` from the man page seems to be rather close to what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating a **spreadsheet**"?

Comment: Maybe this comes close:  `find YOUR_DIRS_HERE -type d -depth -3 -exec du -ms {} ';' | sort -k2 | sed -e 's/\//   /g' >dirs.tsv`  This gives you MB, with each directory level in another column. There's a 'tab' character in the 'sed' expression (converts forward slashes to tabs).